# Delete ID after Select with Group BY

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access
I need to delete all Table1.ids that are as a result of this query. I tried Selecting Table1.id but I got an error saying: you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "id" as part of an aggregate function."

```
SELECT 
Table1.code1,Table1.code2 ,COUNT(*) AS count
FROM 
Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id=Table2.id
Where Table2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY
Table1.code1,
Table1.code2
Having
COUNT(*) > 1
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo need to use `in` operator in your query. If you need to delete all of the rows that meet your condition, then you can use your `table1`'s `code1` column as follows:

```
Delete from Table1  where code1 in 
(
   SELECT 
  Table1.code1
  FROM 
  Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id=Table2.id
  Where Table2.id IS NULL
  GROUP BY
  Table1.code1,
  Table1.code2
  Having
  COUNT(*) > 1 
)
```